# How to apply pagination for a custom WordPress query?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&'); ?>
<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?><br />
<?php echo paginate_links( $args ) ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Here is the query I'm using, it should display the first post title then displays the pagination links, however it only shows the post title without the pagination links. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paginate_links function should go outside the loop and you should use the query variable "paged"

Please see this link http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html for more information on using this.